# How to define the following set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I have a seemingly elementary question from Set nomenclature.

If $B = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}$ such that $A_i \subseteq {B}\;{\forall}\;i$, then does set $B$ have a special name, something similar to subset, superset etc. Or there is no name and I can only refer to $B$ as a union of all $A_i$ sets?

Comment: "The union of the $A_i$" seems like a fitting name for the set which is the union of all $A_i$. Some things in mathematics have many names, but I don't think this is one of them. You could call it a superset of all $A_i$, but then it wouldn't be unique any more, since there are _many_ supersets to any given set or family of sets.

Comment: Yes; $B$ is the *union* of the "family" $\{ A_i \}$ of sets.

Comment: I am certain about the uniqueness of the set $B$ in this case.

Comment: Ok. If any of you puts your comments as an answer, I can mark it accepted.

Comment: You could also say $\;B\;$ is the _least upper bound_ of the $\;A_i\;$, with respect to the $\;\subseteq\;$ partial order on sets. But that would only be appropriate in a context where that order plays some role, I think.  And if you have if you have an additional condition like $\;\langle \forall i : i \leq j : A_i \subseteq A_j \rangle\;$, then $\;B\;$ might be called a limit of some sort.

Comment: Also $B=\cup C$ where $C=\{A_i\mid i\in\mathbb N\}$ wich makes it the *sum* or *sumset* of $C$. This corresponding with axiom SUM.